# Activity and threads

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I am implementing a custom listener interface in an activity which receives data form a data retrieval thread (t1) which in turns starts a data process thread (t2). If the thread (t1) calls the listener interface after that activity is finished, it still fires up the thread (t2).

I am trying to understand how can I avoid this. If t1 call the listener interface after activity is finished or is finishing then t2 should not fire up.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: any code-sample where you fire your threads too!!

Comment: `receives data form a data reterival thread (t1) which in turns starts a data process thread (t2)` .. the whole thing is wrong. `t1` will have to sync then to UI thread. Why don't you use an `AsyncTask` or `IntentService`?

Comment: Thanks for your judgment... Unfortunately, I can't use AsyncTask or IntentService. I am simply looking to see how can t1 that calls into the activity finds if the activity is destroyed or reference to the activity be null.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isDestroyed%28%29 but please consider using `AsyncTask` or something else more suitable...

Comment: You will certainly have to provide code or a more detailed explanation for any kind of diagnosis.  I think we would also like to see what you're doing because ". Unfortunately, I can't use AsyncTask or IntentService" - Them are fightin' words!  I bet you can (and should)

Comment: I have solved this issue by using Handler in the activity. In onResume() I am registering the handler and in onStop() I am unregistering. So if the activity stops, it will not receive any more message from the data retrieval thread.